# MVC Update Model Properties Using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

It's been a while since I did any MVC/JQuery. I'm looking for a solution or a better way of achieving this.

To simplify things, I have a Model with the following properties:

```
public IEnumerable<XmlInputFieldModel> XmlFields { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> BusinessObjectFields { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<XmlSchemaField> MappedFields { get; set; }

public class XmlInputFieldModel
{
    public string XmlElement { get; set;}

    public string XmlValue { get; set; }
}

public class XmlSchemaField
{
    public string XmlElement { get; set; }

    public string BusinessObjectField { get; set; }
}
```

In my View, I'm providing a list of the XmlField Elements and their Values, and for each XmlField I have a dropdown to select a BusinessObjectField, shown below:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.XmlFields)
{
    <div>
        <div style="width: 300px; display: inline-block;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.XmlElement)
        </div>
        <div style="width: 300px; display: inline-block;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.XmlValue)
        </div>
        <div class="busoblist" data-elementid="@(item.XmlElement)" style="display: inline-block;">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BusinessObjectFields, new SelectList(Model.BusinessObjectFields, item.XmlElement))
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
}

<div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block;">
    <input type="button" name="Save" id="Save" />
</div>
```

What I want to happen when I click Save is to populate my MappedFields property with the values from the given Element and the chosen dropdown Field value.  I've attempted this through the script below, but I can't work out how to get from the Key/Value array into my Model.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Save").on("click", function () {

            var mappedFields = new Array();
            $('.busoblist').each(function() {
                var element = $(this).attr('data-elementid');
                mappedFields.push(element + ' : ' + $("option:selected", this).text() + ',');
            });

            var dataToSend = { Val: "Working" };

            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/SetMappedFields",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataToSend,
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.statusText);
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    alert("Result: " + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetMappedFields(string Val)
{
    string newVal = Val;
    return this.RedirectToAction(x => x.Index());
}
```

I explored the Ajax route (commented code), but can't seem to get this to find the controller action.  The above view and script sits in a partial view, where other properties of the base Model are populated.

@CSharper - I've updated the code above, and it's still not hitting the controller :( (I'm using the default HomeController from a starting MVC4 application).  My Error function on the script returns "Error: Not Found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax isn't finding the controller because your not defining Ajax `data:` and giving it the correct parameters. So which in turn

`url: "Home/SetMappedFields" + "?model=" + model + "&fields=" + mappedFields,` 
is not right. If you wanted to call that method from the address bar or using window.open() that would work but ajax expects the parameters differently

(Inside the event that you want to fire the Ajax call.)

```
var dataToSend = {
        Val : "Working"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AjaxCall",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToSend,
        success: function (result) {

        },
    });
})

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjaxCall(string Val)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }


var dataToSend = {
            param1: value,
            param2: value
        };
```

This is how you can reference multiple parameters

Comment: Hi @CSharper, I just tried your Ajax call above, and it's still not finding it. [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SetMappedFields(XmlSchemaModel model, Array fields)

Comment: Ok it's because it's expecting an entire model class and an array. Do me a favor and just remove the "complex" parameters, replace it with a simple string, and hardcode the dataToSend param, just so we can see it work.

Comment: I just tried it with a string, and it's still not getting to the controller. Does it work properly in a partial view?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is in a partial view or not. Are you referencing JQuery correctly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  My _Layout page has references to jquery-2.0.3.js and min, but in case my partial wasn't loading the layout, I added references there too.

Comment: I'm gonna copy and paste the exact code I'm using, and it is calling the controller action

Comment: I've updated my original post, unfortunately it's still not working.  I appreciate your patience and suggestions so far.  I've worked with ajax before and never had many problems, I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing

Comment: I would also do an alert after your "buslist" each function and make sure their is no errors there and the js is getting passed that point. I don't know why else the Ajax won't work

Comment: I've tried that already, as I put an alert on dataToSend to make sure it was being populated. I'm all out of ideas too. I'll keep plugging away at it

Comment: Is your save button causing a form submit?? Maybe the form submit and ajax are getting hung up for some reason

Comment: Doesn't appear so.  I copied the Ajax call into a function for .busoblist on change, and this also fires the Error: Not Found.  I'll have a look at the routing now, to make sure that Home/SetMappedFields is sufficient to find the method.

Comment: Ok, I setup a javascript debugger and followed it through the whole AJAX call, and found the problem.  It didn't like Home/SetMappedFields, as the resulting URL was Home/Home/SetMappedFields.  I removed the Home from my url and it now hits the controller.  Never seen that before... :)

Comment: I've marked your answer, as you have been the most helpful. I have however completely re-written everything to simplify it greatly and use editor templates.